# Prove (p ∧ ~q) ∨ (~p ∨ q) is a tautology with logic laws

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Anyone can help me with this? I have been trying for hours straight to prove this. Truth table does show it is a tautology. I came with a way to do this but I don't think I am correct.

(p ∧ ~q) ∨ (~p ∨ q)

≡ (p ∧  ~q) ∨ (q ∨ ~p)

≡ p ∧ (~q ∨ q) ∨ ~p

≡ p ∧ T ∨ ~p

≡ T ∧ p ∨ ~p

≡ T ∧ T

≡ T

Comment: Hint: De Morgan

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If you take the negation, then you have the statement
\begin{align}
\sim (p \wedge \sim q)\wedge \sim (\sim p \vee q) = \sim (p\wedge \sim q)\wedge (p\wedge \sim q). 
\end{align}
i.e. you have $P\wedge \sim P$.

**Edit:** You could also have shown that $P\vee \sim P$ is a tautology.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, I don't get what take the negation means? Is it like negating the entire statement? Is that like a rule or something that I can use? And also is my method above correct? Sorry for the barrage of questions, I just don't know a lot of things regarding this topic.

Comment: @Han The negation of a tautology is a contradiction; so if you show the negation of a statement is a contradiction then you show the statement is a tautology.  However., you do not need to go so far when you can use deMorgan's rule on the second half of the statement. $$(p\land\lnot q)\lor(\lnot p\lor q)\\\equiv(\text{by de Morgan's Rule})\\(p\land\lnot q)\lor\lnot(p\land\lnot q)$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you so much for replying, so having this statement alone (p∧¬q)∨¬(p∧¬q) is already considered proving that the negation of the statement is a contradiction?

Comment: No. As I said, you did not have to do that. 
 Instead it proves the statement is a tautology, as applying deMorgan's rule to the statement places it in the form of an excluded middle: $\varphi\vee\neg\varphi$. @Han .

Comment: @GrahamKemp Oh I see, I understand now. Thank you so much!